# how to take different strings from an array to form a new array js

Tags: javascript, group

var course = ["HTML", "CSS", "JAVASCRIPT", "PYTHON"]

var student =  {
name: "john doe",
course
}
{
name: "gary lary",
course
}

I want the output to be
group1
[html css javascript python]
john doe is assigned html
gary lary css
and so on

Comment: Please use correct JavaScript syntax and provide full desired output

Comment: this is wrong syntax `var student = [{ name: "john doe", course },{ name: "gary lary", course }]`. it is an array with 2 objects

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you want to combine them. If you don't want to randomize courses to students, you can just match the index of the student with the course. You can use the `map` array method:

```js
let courses = ["HTML", "CSS", "JAVASCRIPT", "PYTHON"]
let students = [ {name: "john doe" },{ name: "gary lary"}]

const studendsWithCourses = students.map((student, index) => ({...student, course: courses[index]}))
```

Note that in this case you'll get an error if the array if students is bigger then the array of courses. You can fix this by changing the map to this:

`const studendsWithCourses2 = students.map((student, index) => ({...student, course: courses[index % courses.length]}))`.

This way, courses will be distributed in order to students and you won't get an error if the students array is bigger than the courses array.